# Recover Xcode project from iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, project, recover

My computer recently crashed and I lost my entire Xcode project. However, the project is till sitting on my iphone, is there any way i can recover it?

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry but I think this is no way to recover your project from iPhone, as it contains already compiled version.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a painful lesson about version control and backups

There is no way to get the Xcode project back from the compiled app.

Answer (score 0):

if you can access your iPhone and could get to the folder where the app was installed then you will fnd couple of files you might be able to use. Esp *.png files. There are also some *nib files - but I don't know if/how they can be loaded back into xCode somehow.

You will also get the *strings files back. But possibly most important in this folder there are also *h files of your project.

So I guess that will save you already couple of hours - all you need is to get to your iPhones app folder. I use iPhone Explorer, but anything else should work too.

ps don't know how it can be done on a non-jailbroken phone though

good luck!

use TimeMachine in the future - its simple and doesn't burdon your MAC during development...